# Array assignment not updating in Verilog

Tags: arrays, verilog, variable-assignment

I have the following code:

```
reg [7:0]data[0:7];
always @(posedge clk) begin
    data[var1]<=var2;
    $write("%d:%d:%d", var1, var2, data[var1]);
end
```

3:100:    x is printed, so the data assignment is not working correctly. Why is this?

Comment: Can you please provide your testbench and output as well?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a non-blocking assignment to `data`, you are seeing the current value of `data` not the value to be updated. Use $strobe instead of $display, or better yet, put the $write in a different always block the prints on the negative edge.

Comment: That works for the variable, thank you!! Would you have any idea why this doesn't work for a reg array?

Comment: If `var1` and `var2` are also being assigned with non-blocking assignments, then the current value of `var` is used to index into `data`